# How can I make ruby ShellWords.shellescape work with multibyte characters?

Tags: ruby, regex, windows, character-encoding, escaping

I have been trying to call exec with an argument that contains multibyte characters that come from an environment variable on Windows, but have not found a solution that works yet.  Here is what I have been able to debug so far.

For simplicity's sake assume that I have a directory called "Seán" that I am trying to use as an argument to exec.  If I just call

```
exec 'script', "Se\u00E1n".encode("IBM437")
```

The script that is exec'ed cannot find the file because the arg gets tweaked in such a way that the accented character is lost.  If I do the following it works, but this is bad practice as the arg should be escaped before it goes to the shell.

```
exec "script #{"Se\u00E1n".encode("IBM437")}"
```

So my thought was that I would just use [shellescape](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.7/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape) to protect the use of exec.

```
require 'shellwords'
exec "script #{"Se\u00E1n".encode("IBM437").shellescape}"
```

But the problem is that it escapes the special character so that it looks like the following - "Se\án".  I figured out where this is happening and it is coming from this [regular expression](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_7/lib/shellwords.rb#L134).

```
str.gsub!(/([^A-Za-z0-9_\-.,:\/@\n])/, "\\\\\\1")
```

Which at first glance seems to escape characters not in a known good set of shell characters.  Unfortunately this set does not include special characters and so I run into problems.

What I am looking for is a regex that would do shell escaping that does not mess up special characters so that I can escape these args before passing them to exec.

Comment: Why not just rename the file to be executed?

Comment: @Aetherus that is not really an option, as this is software that we have written that is installed on another users computer.  We install into a directory to which they have an environment variable set.  This directory is the one which has the special characters in it, so we really have no control over what it is named.

Comment: @RansomBriggs: Did you try [`s.gsub(/([^\p{L}0-9_.,:\/@\n-])/, "\\\\\\1")`](http://ideone.com/qReAs0)? Well, if you can modify that method, or if you can create your custom version, of course.

Comment: @Mariano I want to escape things so they are safe to pass down as part of a shell command string. The regex from shellwords works by escaping all characters except known safe ones.  The problem is that the list of known safe does not include special characters.

Comment: @stribizhev I will check out your regex next time I am at a computer (on holiday right now)

Comment: @Mariano - I wanted to escape all characters which you should not pass down to a shell command, and in the process leaving non-ascii letters unescaped.

Comment: @stribizhev The regex from your comment is exactly what I was looking for.  If you form that into an answer, and leave a note that \p{L} maps to the Unicode character’s General Category /\p{L}/ - 'Letter', I will accept the answer and award the bounty to you.

Comment: @stribizhev - In your answer could you also replace 0-9 with the character class for number as well?

Comment: Just got back home, and though my wife starts grumbling, I am adding an answer :)

Comment: Added, please check. I will add more details if necessary once I have more time.

Comment: @Mariano I just accepted another answer, so update yours only if you desire to.

Comment: @RansomBriggs I posted the alternative to stribizhev's answer, to only escape shell metacharacters and unbalanced quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `/([^A-Za-z0-9_\-.,:\/@\n])/` only handles ASCII letters and digits, not all Unicode letters. The `[^...]` is a [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that matches all characters *other than those specified in the class*. So, all `Я`, `Ц`, `Ą` are removed with that expression as they are not matched with `[A-Za-z]`.

What you need is to add *shorthand classes to exclude all Unicode letters and digits*. To make it even more safe, we can add a diacritic class so as to keep diacritics, too:

```
str.gsub(/([^\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}_.,:\/@\n-])/, "\\\\\\1")
```

Here, `\p{L}` matches all Unicode base letters, `\p{M}` matches all diacritics, and `\p{N}` matches any Unicode digits.

Note that a hyphen does not need to be escaped when placed at the start/end of the character class (or after a valid range or a shorthand character class).

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

**Escaped characters**

[image: Metacharacters]

---

**Code**

```ruby
String.class_eval do
    def escapeshell()
        # Escape shell special characters
        self.gsub!(/[#-&(-*;<>?\[-^`{-~\u00FF]/, '\\\\\0')
        # Escape unbalanced quotes (single and double quotes)
        self.gsub!(/(["'])(?:([^"']*(?:(?!\1)["'][^"']*)*)\1)?/) do
            if $2.nil? 
                '\\' + $1
            else
                # and escape quotes inside (e.g. "x'x" or 'y"y')
                qt = $1
                qt + $2.gsub(/["']/, '\\\\\0') + qt
            end
        end
        self
    end
end


# Test it
str = "(dir *.txt & dir \"\\some dir\\Sè\u00E1ñ*.rb\") | sort /R >Filé.txt 2>&1"
puts 'String:'
puts str

puts "\nEscaped:"
puts str.escapeshell
```

**Output**

```
String:
(dir *.txt & dir "\some dir\Sèáñ*.rb") | sort /R >Filé.txt 2>&1

Escaped:
\(dir \*.txt \& dir "\\some dir\\Sèáñ\*.rb"\) \| sort /R \>Filé.txt 2\>\&1
```

<kbd>[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/Hb50mK)</kbd>

---

### Description

**Metacharacters**

Considering the shell metacharacters that should be escaped:

```
# & % ; ` | * ? ~ < > ^ ( ) [ ] { } $ \ \u00FF
```

We can include each character in the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
[#&%;`|*?~<>^()\[\]{}$\\\u00FF]
```

Which is exactly the same as:

```
/[#-&(-*;<>?\[-^`{-~\u00FF]/
```

Then, we use [`gsub!()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) to prepend a backslash before any character that in the class:

```ruby
str.gsub!(/[#-&(-*;<>?\[-^`{-~\u00FF]/, '\\\\\0')
```

**Quotes**

Only unbalanced quotes need to be escaped. This is important to preserve the command's arguments. With the following expression we match balanced quotes:

```
/(["'])[^"']*(?:(?!\1)["'][^"']*)*)\1/
```

As well as unbalanced, making the last part optional

```
/(["'])(?:[^"']*(?:(?!\1)["'][^"']*)*)\1)?/
```

But we also need to escape quotes inside another pair. That is single quotes inside double quotes and vice-versa. So we'll nest another `gsub()` to replace in the text matched inside quotes (`$2`):

```ruby
str.gsub!(/(["'])(?:([^"']*(?:(?!\1)["'][^"']*)*)\1)?/) do
    if $2.nil? 
        '\\' + $1
    else
        qt = $1
        qt + $2.gsub(/["']/, '\\\\\0') + qt
    end
end
```

Comment: What I need is the opposite, I need to be able to escape untrusted user input so that I can pass it down to the shell.  I need it to work exactly like [shellescape](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.7/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape) and escape the problematic shell characters.  The reason I cannot use shellwords is that it escapes multibyte characters.

Comment: @RansomBriggs I was under the impression you only wanted to escape multibyte chars, I've updated the answer to deal with shell metacharacters, considering a special case for quotes, where only unbalanced quotes should be escaped.